# Slack get conversation history for a specific thread

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to fetch the conversation history for a specific thread. I am using

```
const history = await this.slack.conversations.history({
  channel,
  latest: threadTs,
});
```

But I am getting the conversation history for the whole channel instead of just for the the threadTs that I am passing to latest. Is what Im trying to do possible? I am using the 'latest' argument because it was suggesting in another StackOverflow post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, you've since found the answer yourself, but just in case: the API method you're looking for is [`conversations.replies`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.replies). It takes a `channel` and a `ts` parameter, where the latter is the identifier for the message which started the thread.

From the documentation page linked above:

> This Conversations API method returns an entire thread (a message plus all the messages in reply to it), while conversations.history method returns only parent messages.

One small note: as you can see, the returned list will **always** contain the originating message (the one whose `ts` you're passing).